# How to install MySQL on separate box from IIS 7

Tags: php, mysql, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7

I've got two servers running Server 2008 r2. I've set up one sever as the webserver with IIs7.0, asp.net, php, nodejs, etc. And I have put MySQL and MongoDB on the other server.

As best I can tell they are installed correctly and working. The method I use to check things are ok on the webserver is a simple hello world, checking type aspx and php pages are served correctly. On the database side I'm using the command line and able to check versions and issue simple commands.

However, I'm not able to figure out how to integrate the two servers. How do I tell IIs and PHP where to find MySQL? I've done extensive searching but I've only found instructions that seem to install them on the same box or posts that say "Yes it is a good idea to put them on different boxes" but don't then go on to say how you do that.

Specifically I'm trying to install phpMyAdmin, I figure once I get that running the rest will be easy.

I'm not sure if I'm looking for a service or a handler or what not. Any advice or directions you can point me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You install it.  You then configure MySQL to allow remote connections from the IP Address assigned to the other server.  You then connect to the remote server instead of a local server.

Comment: @Ramhound Presumably that would be allow remote connections *on the LAN IP address* rather than any public IP address of the other server?